# PUT method not working with ExpressJS and React

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb, express, backend

I have been following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xKs2IZZya7c) and have come across a hurdle where the 'PUT' method doesn't seem to work.

When a user edits a post and then proceeds to update, it returns a 'net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET' and fails to fetch. In my 'EditPost.jsx', the form calls a function on submit:

```
async function editPost(e) {
 const data = new FormData();
 data.set("title", title);
 data.set("summary", summary);
 data.set("content", content);
 data.set("id", id);
 if (files?.[0]) {
   data.set("file", files?.[0]);
 }

 e.preventDefault();
 const response = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/post", {
   method: "PUT",
   body: data,
   credentials: "include",
 });
 if (response.status === 200) {
   setRedirect(true);
 }
}
```

In the index.js file:

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const app = express();
//jwt
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
//private key
const private = "sdkjgfbnaihfgbiwQOIG";
//cookie parser
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const multer = require("multer");
const uploadFile = multer({ dest: "uploads/" });
//filesystem
const fs = require("fs");
//models
const User = require("./models/User");
const Post = require("./models/Post");

//create endpoint for upload files
app.use("/uploads", express.static(__dirname + "/uploads"));
app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: "http://localhost:5173" }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

app.put("/post", uploadFile.single("file"), async (req, res) => {
 let newPath = null;
 if (req.file) {
  //get file type
  const { originalname, path } = req.file;
  const part = originalname.split(".");
  const ext = part[part.length - 1];
  //get pathname
  newPath = path + "." + ext;
  fs.renameSync(path, newPath);
 }

 const { token } = req.cookies;
 jwt.verify(token, private, {}, async (err, info) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  //check if user id from token is equal to author id
  const { title, summary, content, id } = req.body;
  const post = await Post.findById(id);
  const isAuthor = JSON.stringify(post.author) === JSON.stringify(info.id);
  if (!isAuthor) {
    return res.status(400).json("Invalid Author");
  }
  await post.update({
    title,
    summary,
    content,
    file: newPath ? newPath : post.file,
  });
  res.json(post);
 });
});
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.